# "I would" vs "I will"

Tags: clauses

> "like hell I would"

or

> "like hell I will"

Which one is the way to go to express that something is just ***pure awesome***?

And is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Depends on the tense you wish to convey. Can you give us a context with an example sentence? "Like hell" is usually used to convey the opposite. "like hell I would" is saying there's no way you would do that.

Comment: My affiliate partner ask me to improve revenue

Comment: I said like hell I would

Comment: please add the context to the OP, with an example of possible usage.

Comment: Saying "I will" or "I would" doesn't change the fact that "Like hell" changes it to the opposite.

Comment: If you responded "Like hell I will/would" to someone asking you to improve revenue, it will come off as you saying, "I will not improve revenue."

Comment: If you want to say you would definitely not do something even in theory, say "Like hell I would!"  If you want to say you will definitely not do something in reality, say "Like hell I will!" meaning you will not do it at all.

Comment: I would suggest that, until you intuitively know when to use "would" vs "will" in such phrases, you avoid using them.

Comment: For pure awesome you have to use _heck_ or (arguably) _heckola_.

Comment: I thought I will really do it. ha ha ha

Answer (score 2):

**would** = use if the speaker is talking about a hypothetical

**will** = if it is a possibility to actually do.

Ex:

> "If you were president, would you talk to all the celebrities?"
>
> Like hell I would!

Ex:

> "Will you go with me to the cinema?"
>
> Like hell I will

(careful intonation makes the difference between a 'no' and a 'yes)

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like-hell

Comment: so like hell can mean very much or not